# How to get tag of the user in OneSignal?

Tags: c#, android, onesignal

I'm using OneSignal to send notifications to users in my Android application.
At the moment I can get the PlayerId/deviceId by using idsAvailable() and send notifications to that user.

When I initialize OneSignal in my app I send a tag (userEmail) using sendTag method to differentiate users. Now i want to send notifications to users whose tags I have already set.

How to get those tags in C# Webapi because i'm using OneSignal REST Api to send notifications from my C# server.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a a list of a users' tags through the OneSignal REST API using the following endpoint: https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#view-device

You can also send notifications through the OneSignal REST API by specifying a list of tags of users that should receive teh notification.